# Java selenium code not working on chrome browser but same code works on firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

This is my code.
The code works fine for firefox, but when i run it on google chrome, browser opens and identifies username field but does not read data from excel and send it to the element.

```
package test_script;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import common_functions.commonFunctionRepo;
import common_objects.*;
import excel_utilites.ExcelUtils;
import utilities.Constant;


public class AddPgm_TC_02 
{
    @Test

    public void AddPgm() throws Exception
    {

    //Set Test browser to Firefox driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./exe_files/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //Launch the url
        commonFunctionRepo.launchDucky(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData, "TC_02");

        for (int i=1; i<=ExcelUtils.getRowcount(); i++)

        {

        String Uname = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 1);
        String Pwd = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 2);

      //Login
            commonFunctionRepo.login(driver, Uname,Pwd);
            System.out.println("Logged in Successfully");


        String pgmNameTxt = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 3);
        String descTxt = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 4);
        String expRes = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 5);


      //Click on Menu
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.id("vappmenu"));
        menu.click();

    //Click on Navigation
        WebElement navigation   = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("paper-icon-item[title='Navigation']"));
        navigation.click();

    //Click on Manage Program
        WebElement subManagePgm = driver.findElement(By.id("Manage Programs"));
        subManagePgm.click();
        System.out.println("Navigated Manage Program Successfully");

    //Click on Add New button - need id 
        WebElement addNew = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iron-icon[class='style-scope programs-panel x-scope iron-icon-1'][icon='add-box']"));
        addNew.click();

    //Type Program Name
        WebElement pgmName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='Program Name']"));
        commonFunctionRepo.SendData(driver, pgmName,  pgmNameTxt);  

        //Type Description - need id
        WebElement desc = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("paper-textarea[class='program-upsert-full style-scope program-upsert'][label='Description']"));
        commonFunctionRepo.SendData(driver, desc,  descTxt);    

    //Click on Save
        WebElement saveBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("paper-button[title='Save Program']"));
        saveBtn.click();    

    //Get Success Message - need id
        WebElement successMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("paper-toast[title = 'Program created successfully']>span[id='label'][class='style-scope paper-toast']"));
        String msg = commonFunctionRepo.getTextFrom(driver, successMsg);        
        System.out.println("Message is  - "+msg);

    //logout
        driver.findElement(By.id("vappmenu")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//paper-item[@title='Logout']")).click();

        Boolean status = commonFunctionRepo.strCompare(msg, expRes);

        ExcelUtils.setCellData(msg, i, 6);

        if(status)
        {
            ExcelUtils.setCellData("pass", i, 7);
        }
        else enter code here
        {
            ExcelUtils.setCellData("Fail", i, 7);
        }

        }

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Console error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 133 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0436FTE', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\khaji\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir272_9014}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4771cb9a4b4ab55ebe166a8fee9a4414
```

Comment: Try to upgrade `chromedriver`

Comment: If you look at the complete stacktrace (what you shared is not the full stacktrace), it should tell you the exact line that is causing this crash. In all cases, you might want to try upgrading to the latest chromedriver version and see if that helps.